# Prove $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the series $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$, where $f(n)$ is a polynomial of degree more than one and never zero, converges. In order to do so, I'm trying to use the comparison test and the fact $\sum \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ converges if $\alpha\gt 1$.

I almost sure we have to use these facts to prove this question, but I couldn't use them to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The sum needn't even be defined: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-1}$ is not defined, for example. You need to impose some condition so that the summands are never dividing by zero. Once you've done that, it is essentially the same trick as you have used before to deal with limits of rational functions: given $1/p(n)$ where $p$ is degree $k$, write it as $\frac{1}{n^k} \frac{n^k}{p(n)}$ and argue that $\frac{n^k}{p(n)}$ is bounded.

Comment: @Ian see my edit please

Comment: Limit comparison test makes it easy.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is a polynomial, therefore it has finitely many roots. Presumably you mean that $f(n) \neq 0$ for any of the integers over which you are summing.

The key is really two bounds for $f(z)$: let
$$ f(z) = z^{m}+a_{m-1}z^{m-1} + \dotsb + a_0 $$
(clearly the assumption that $f$ is monic makes no difference), and define
$$ A = \max_{k}{|a_k|} $$
Now suppose $|z|>A+1$. Then
$$ |f(z)/z^m-1| = \left\lvert \frac{1}{|z|^m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} a_k z^k \right\rvert \leqslant \frac{A}{|z|^m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \lvert z \rvert^k = \frac{A(1-|z|^{-m})}{|z|-1} \leqslant 1-|z|^{-m} $$
It follows that $f(z)/z^m \to 1$ as $z \to \infty$, so there are positive numbers $b,B$ so that
$$ b|z|^m < |f(z)| < B|z|^m $$
for all $|z|>1+A$. This only excludes a finite number of $n$, so you can sandwich the rest of your series between two multiples of $|z|^m$, and then apply the convergence of $\sum n^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>1$.